# In Javascript: Can you convert a if/else statement to a switch?

Tags: javascript

I tried to convert my **working If/ Else statement** in Javascript to a Switch Statement. However I could not get the Switch Statement to work for some reason. Is this possible/did I something wrong/ syntax error?  I have included the code below: Can someone clarify this for me, thanks.

Working If/Else statement:

```
function displayCityInfo() {
    var cd = document.getElementById("cityData").value;
    var h2 = document.getElementById("main");



    switch(cd){
      var spacing = "";
      case 1:

      for(i=0; i<cities.length; i++){
          spacing += "City of " + cities[i].city
          + ", latitude is " + cities[i].latitude + "<p>";
      }
      h2.innerHTML = "<h2>Results</h2>" + spacing;

        break;

      case 2:

      for(i=0; i<cities.length; i++){
          spacing += "City of " + cities[i].city
          + " population is " + cities[i].population + "<p>";
      }
      h2.innerHTML = "<h2>Results</h2>" + spacing;

      break;

      case 3:

      for(i=0; i<cities.length; i++){
          spacing += "City of " + cities[i].elevation
          + ", latitude is " + cities[i].elevation + "<p>";
      }
      h2.innerHTML = "<h2>Results</h2>" + spacing;

      break;

    }



}
```

Javascript Switch statement that is not working:

```
function displayCityInfo() {
    var cd = document.getElementById("cityData").value;
    var h2 = document.getElementById("main");



    switch(cd){
      var spacing = "";
      case 1:

      for(i=0; i<cities.length; i++){
          spacing += "City of " + cities[i].city
          + ", latitude is " + cities[i].latitude + "<p>";
      }
      h2.innerHTML = "<h2>Results</h2>" + spacing;

        break;

      case 2:

      for(i=0; i<cities.length; i++){
          spacing += "City of " + cities[i].city
          + " population is " + cities[i].population + "<p>";
      }
      h2.innerHTML = "<h2>Results</h2>" + spacing;

      break;

      case 3:

      for(i=0; i<cities.length; i++){
          spacing += "City of " + cities[i].elevation
          + ", latitude is " + cities[i].elevation + "<p>";
      }
      h2.innerHTML = "<h2>Results</h2>" + spacing;

      break;

    }



}
```

Comment: Looks like you pasted the `switch` statement example twice, I don't see an `if/else` version

Comment: Also, what is your intended goal?  The things you are doing in each `case` statement are far outside what I generally see done in a standard `case`-- it's at least non-idiomatic, and honestly I'm wondering if it would even run without an error...  Finally, can you expand on what about it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Switch statement except `case` or `default` after initiating switch. Which means you can't put `var spacing = "";` below `switch(cd){`. Declare the variable above the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Just use default, like this:

```
switch(x){
  case 1:
    //do stuff
  break;
  default:
    //do the stuff that you would do in the else block
  break;
}
```

Note: I'm not sure why you would use this over if/else, but you could add onto it, like:

```
  case 1:
    //do stuff
  break;
  case 2:
    //do other stuff
  break;
  default:
    //do the stuff that you would do in the else block
  break;
```